# Java Srping nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError

Tags: java, spring, spring-boot

I have some entity classes and try to get all data from db, but I got the nested exception problem. Please see details below:
the Worker entity:

```
   Worker{
        @Id
        private Long id;

        @Transient
        private List<WorkerDepartment> workerDepartments;

        @Transient
        private List<WorkerDepartmentPosition> workerDepartmentPositions;

        @Transient
        private List<WorkerAdjustmentBonus> workerAdjustmentBonus;
    }
```

WorkerDepartment entity

```
    WorkerDepartment{
        @Id
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JsonBackReference(value = "worker")
        @JoinColumn(name = "worker_id")
        private worker worker;

    }
```

WorkerDepartmentPosition entity

```
    WorkerDepartmentPosition{
        @Id
        private Long id;

        @Column(name = "worker_id")
        private Long workerId;
    }
```

WorkerBonus

```
    WorkerBonus{
        @Id
        private Long id;

        @ManyToOne
        @JsonBackReference(value = "worker")
        @JoinColumn(name = "worker_id")
        private worker worker;

        @ManyToOne
        @JoinColumn(name = "payment_id")
        private WorkerPayment employeePayment;

        @Column(name = "bonus")
        private Double bonus;
    }
```

I try to get all worker and the response data is

```
{"status":"SUCCESS","data":[have full data],"message":"successfully done"}{"status":"ERROR","message":"Handler dispatch failed; nested exception is java.lang.StackOverflowError"}
```

Please advise me.

Answer (score 0):

The issue might come from the cross-reference of e.g. `Worker` and `WorkerDepartment`. When Jackson tries to deserialize your objects, it travels through the *object graph* and once it accesses the `WorkerDepartment` attribute, it goes back to the `Worker` and does this cycle over-and-over.

As you already use `@JsonBackReference(value = "worker")` you almost already fixed the problem, but you need `@JsonManagedReference` on the other side:

```
public class Worker{
    @Id
    private Long id;

    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<WorkerDepartment> workerDepartments;

    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<WorkerDepartmentPosition> workerDepartmentPositions;

    @JsonManagedReference
    private List<WorkerAdjustmentBonus> workerAdjustmentBonus;
}
```

Baeldung also provides [a good tutorial](https://www.baeldung.com/jackson-bidirectional-relationships-and-infinite-recursion) on this for further reading.

Comment: Hi rieckpil, I face a issue reated to Http 415 Unsupported Media type error with JSON when add the @JsonManagedReference ..:(